# WinForm C# : How to prevent Snipping tool or Snip & Sketch tool to capture screen shot of the particular child window?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I would like to prevent capturing screen using snipping tools. I've already prevented Print Screen by registering KeyUp event and clearing clipboard. I would like to prevent capturing screen only for particular Child Form (Popup Dialog).

I tried Form Deactivate event but as soon as user click on Snipping tool's New Snip function, it activates my application.

**Edit**

I found a gimmick. Please note that neither it's bulletproof solution nor its good User Experience but it might be helpful for some of you out there.

**Steps**

1. Take panel, set background color property to gray (or any of your choice).
2. Make sure that panel is hidden and it's SendToBack.
3. Register panel's click event.
4. Register Form Deactivate event.
5. On Form Deactivate, set that panel's visibility to true, dock it to fill screen and set BringToFront. So when user switch to other application or click anywhere outside the app, grayed out panel will cover your actual screen.
6. When user switch back to the application, make them click on panel to reopen (unhide) your actual screen.

Again, as I said this is gimmick and not good User Experience but it might help someone like me whose main objective is to prevent users from taking screen shot of sensitive data.

User can still take picture using their phone or camera or screenshot VM by running your application in VM. So my solution is not bulletproof but at least it will definitely make it not so easy.

Cheers!!

Comment: Even fi you could, what's stopping anyone just getting access to the DC and capturing the screen, or another application they download.

Comment: @TheGeneral You're right but let's just say its part of requirement to "secure" sensitive data.

Comment: If security is a concern, you might be better to limit apps with a group policy, otheriwise you could poll the process list and kill apps you dont like, however you will be chasing this solution for ever, any kid would be able to bypass it. Lastly you could probably write some sort of dll injection unit, that monitors for a few win api calls espectially the ones to with the Device context , but still this would be a lot of work and very invasive likely to crash random apps

Comment: You are making it *harder* for users and not *securing* data. Such requirement is simply stupid. If you tells us what data you are trying to secure, maybe there is a better solution. [Related](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/263112/156546).

Comment: @Sinatr To be fair, security _always_ makes things _"harder for users"_ and is _never_ _"stupid"_.

Comment: @Sinatr Actually I've to allow users (authorized company's employees) to see the data for their daily operations. It's part of their job. But recently we found that some of them are capturing screenshot and taking that data outside company's premises in form of printout or sharing it digitally, which they are not suppose to do. So I've been asked to prevent them from taking screen shot, if possible of course.

Comment: I don't think Windows has functions to prevent screen capture of application windows. Even if it had, you could just run the app in a VM, and capture the VM screen. Better to go with TheGeneral's suggestion of limiting who has access to the app in the first place.

Comment: And if employees share/print content without permission, I dare say that is more a case for disciplinary action than going on a rabbit chase in code.

Comment: @Fredd, I believe the right course of action is to clearly prohibit it. Moreover you can modify displayed image to *mark* it (with either PC or user id). This way, once you found screenshot somewhere, you will know who did that and can apply actions against person.

Comment: @MickyD, I mean requirement to prohibit taking screenshots is stupid. Everybody has handy with camera.

Comment: @Sinatr BTW, _Kaspersky Safe Money_ is able to _["Block capturing screenshots in Protected Browser"](https://help.kaspersky.com/KIS/2017/en-EN/82967.htm)_ for Windows 8, Windows 8.1 and Windows 10

Comment: @dumetrulo You're right about capturing VM but my application is only running on authorized company's machine and there is no VM installed on it, nor they can install anything else.

Comment: @Sinatr it sounds good idea to add watermark on image with PC# or UserId. Any lead on this how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Use pInvoke to call `SetWindowDisplayAffinity(hwnd, WDA_MONITOR);`

From [Old New thing](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20200506-00/?p=103730)

> That said, the customer could modify their proprietary program to call the Set­Window­Display­Affinity function to indicate that the window contents should not be included in screen captures, as I noted some time ago. The desktop compositor will prevent those pixels from being included in Bit­Blt and other screen capture functions.
>
> UWP applications can set the [Application­View.Is­Screen­Capture­Enabled](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/DisablingScreenCapture) property to false to exclude a view from screen capture functions.

That said, this only makes it slightly more difficult to capture data. There are ways around it, and whatever you do, you cannot prevent anyone from whipping out a mobile phone and taking a picture, or just writing down the important parts to a notepad.

Comment: Another application can obtain hwnd and set affinity to `WDA_NONE`.

Comment: @Sinatr As I mentioned, there are ways around it. I'm not knowledgeable enough to list all of them, but I'm confident that there are more than one way to circumvent it.